# Dynamically set attribute on component in html template angular 2

Tags: data-binding, angular, angular2-template

I am trying to set an attribute on a component if a certain expression is true. Could someone give me an example?

What I have now:

```
 <div [danger]="inArray(choice.likers, user, id)"></div>
```

but this does not compile.

inArray is my own method which returns true or false.
What I would like to see is, if the expression returns true, the output will be

```
<div danger></div>
```

In angular 1 there was this: ng-attr-... statement that did exactly the above.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

To set an attribute use **[attribute binding](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding)**:

```
 <div [attr.danger]="inArray(choice.likers, user, id)"></div>
```

If you want to show a empty attribute conditionally return empty string or null in `inArray()`:

```
inArray() {
    let value;
    if (isInArray) {
      value = '';
    } else {
      value = null;
    }
    return value;
  }
```

so the attribute will empty or the danger attribute dont exist. The result is:

```
<div danger></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment muetzerich. This code allows me to set the value of the attribute dynamically but what I would like to achieve is to set the attribute itself.

Comment: To clarify: the output with your code is: danger="true", but I would like to only set the attribute not give it a value.

Comment: try this  [attr.danger]="inArray(choice.likers, user, id) ? true : null" -> null remove the danger attribute

Comment: I am sorry to say but still the same problem: danger="true". Seems like this is not working for attributes. Although I found an example in the docs that does work [disabled]. I will try to create a plunkr.

Comment: an empty string '' instead of true seems to do the trick. Thanks!

Comment: I am using *ngFor and want something likethis < input data-time = {{data.service_id}}> but it is giving error.  Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'data-time' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.